# Parallel $http calls using same object

Tags: angularjs

I have the following function in a controller:

```
this.someFunction = function() {
    var filter = {
        type: 'E'
    };

    someService.httpPostFunction(filter).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

    filter.type = 'H';
    someService.httpPostFunction(filter).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });

    filter.type = 'W';
    someService.httpPostFunction(filter).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

This is the `someService.httpPostFunction` :

```
httpPostFunction: function(filter) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var httpPromise = $http.post(url,filter)
    .then(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error.data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The `someService.httpPostFunction` returns me different data based on `filter.type`. I want them to run in parallel. However, this function behaves as if the `filter.type` is set to `'W'` even on the first `httpPostFunction` call.

Creating copies of the `filter` variable, changing `type` of the copies and then passing the copies gives me correct results but this is not feasible. How do I get the code working correctly using the same variable?

Comment: Post the code of someService.httpPostFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$q.all` to send multiple http request parallel

```
var filterObj = {
   type: ['E', 'H', 'W']
};
var arr = [];
for(item in filterObj.type){
   arr.push(someService.httpPostFunction(item))
}
$q.all(arr).then(function(responses) {
    console.log( responses[0].data);
    console.log( responses[1].data);
    console.log( responses[2].data); 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array to store the promises and then use $q.all to catch all the promises something like below

```
this.someFunction = function() {
    var filterObj = {
        type: ['E', 'H', 'W']
    };
    var promises = filterObj.type.map(function(v) {
        return someService.httpPostFunction(v);
    });
    $q.all(promises).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response[0]);   //type E
        console.log(response[1]);   //type H
        console.log(response[2]);   //type W
    });
};
```